# How to check/display the inklevel of a printer (Canon MG5150)?

Tags: printing, canon

My Canon MG5150 doesn't work neither with Inkblot nor with Mtink (Epson Use). I tried two distros: Linux Mint 13 Maya and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I found out that TurboPrint works, but it's no alternative for me because it is very expensive and not open source.

**ink** is a package that uses `libinklevel5`, it's available in the repositories but it has no graphical user interface.

Is there a Gnome application based on libinklevel5 that I could use?
Can you suggest other packages that might work, too?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Achieve better printing results, be able to print at all, or check the inklevel of your printer (which libinlevel seems to be good for)? Please be more precice and make your question comprehensible! Thank you.

Comment: I just want to see ink level. Printing works fine, even if I must use Canon's driver ("Linux IJ Printer Driver"). Thanks Cauon.

Comment: So oyou tried **ink** and it did work for you? Am I guessing this right?

Comment: Yes it is : ink works, but is command Line only

Answer (score 2):

After doing some serious digging I have found the solution to this for Canon Printers.  Mine is an MP495 but these two command are worth documenting.

1. cngpig -P
2. cngpigmonmp495 *****This one gives me my ink levels******  It is installed in the /usr/bin directory.

Comment: Hi ! i've not been noticed someone replied, sorry. Where can I get cngpig ? I can't find it on my filesystem ! Thanks :)